# Map certain elements of one array to another array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this:

```
[1,2,3,2,4,5,3,7,8]
```

I want to map them to other elements 2=> 'b', 3=>'a'

```
[1,'b','a','b',4,5,'a',7,8]
```

What are some strategies to do it.

Answer (score 10):

```
arr = [1,2,3,2,4,5,3,7,8]
h = { 2=>'b', 3=>'a' }

h.default_proc = ->(_,k) { k }
h.values_at(*arr)
  #=> [1, "b", "a", "b", 4, 5, "a", 7, 8]
```

Comment: what's -> symbol doing

Comment: Muhammad, that's the ["stabby"](http://isotope11.com/blog/stabby-lambda) syntax for writing lambdas, which was introduced in Ruby v1.9. As you see, I'm using it with the method [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D).

Comment: I like the way you turned the problem inside-out.

Comment: Quite elegant approach.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : I must say you are so creative wid Ruby. Always comeup wid neat solution. 1+ for default_proc

Comment: Thanks, @Gagan. If I can offer a small suggestion: work on interesting questions that are stale. This question was pretty fresh when I answered, but I often spend time on stale questions. Yesterday I posted an answer to a question that was asked in 2008 (unusually stale for me).  The reason is that if a question is stale, all the obvious solutions have already been offered, so you are forced to be creative to come up with a good, original answer.

Comment: As much as I like that you want to teach people cool features of Ruby, @falsetru's answer would be the one I would hope to see when looking at production code.

Comment: @ndn, I might well agree with you if I wrote Ruby code for a living. As it is, I don't and never did, so I can only guess what constitutes good production code.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) as a mapping and use [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to get a new array mapped:

```
mapping = {2 => 'b', 3 => 'a' }
[1,2,3,2,4,5,3,7,8].map { |x| mapping.fetch(x, x) }
=> [1, "b", "a", "b", 4, 5, "a", 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible solution, similar to [@falsetru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001753/2988):

```
mapping = Hash.new {|_, v| v }.merge(2 => 'b', 3 => 'a')
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8].map(&mapping.method(:[]))
# => [1, 'b', 'a', 'b', 4, 5, 'a', 7, 8]
```

In [Feature #11262 – Make more objects behave like "Functions"](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11262) on the Ruby issue tracker, I suggested that `Hash`es should behave like functions from keys to values, i.e. they should implement `call` and `to_proc`, which would allow you to pass the `mapping` directly as the transformation function to `map`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8].map(&mapping)
# => [1, 'b', 'a', 'b', 4, 5, 'a', 7, 8]
```

Until my suggestion gets implemented (which is probably "never", considering that nobody has even looked at it in two months), you need this monkey patch to get it to work:

```
module HashAsFunction
  refine Hash do
    alias_method :call, :[]

    def to_proc
      method(:call).to_proc
    end
  end
end

using HashAsFunction
```